# How to pass json along with image when making http request callout in salesforce?

Tags: apex, integration, json

How do I pass parameters inside the request body, when I am using the property request.setbodyasblob(), ( because I also have an image which I need to send as a part of the request to the endpoint)?

I also need to send a json parameters file along with the image in the request body, but am unable to do so.

Comment: Typically one of the parameters would be for the image and would be set to the blob value not the whole body. Without seeing what the documentation is on the endpoint you are trying to hit and the code you are trying to use,  there is not much help that can be provided.

Comment: Hi Eric, following s a piece of the code I'm referring to:
....
        request.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
        request.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; charset="UTF-8"; boundary="' + Boundary + '"');
        request.setHeader('Content-Length', string.valueOf(bodyBlob.size()));
        HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
        system.debug('***********response: '+response.getbody());
.....
I need to add a json file too, inside the body now.